# PHP strange behaviour with charset ISO-8859-1 and form input

Tags: php, input, encoding

I am discovering strange behaviour of PHP with form input.

The server has settings via **.htaccess**

```
AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1
php_flag default_charset ISO-8859-1
```

Just having a simple form with a text input. When entering

```
#+´´+#
```

(the character in the middle is two times 0xB4 = DEC 180).

When doing a var_dump() of the form input field I am getting an

```
string(16) "#+´´+#"
```

Does anybody have an explanation for that?

And an idea how to get only ISO-8859-1 input? (I want to avoid to manually convert all input).

Besides: Any trial with mb_convert_encoding() and iconv() does NOT remove this special characters!

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you're receiving the character encoded as HTML entity, but you're looking at the `var_dump` in a browser which renders the HTML entity as a character.

Comment: Yes, I agree according var_dump.

Comment: But: Why does PHP convert als HTML entity? And how to "fix" that?

Comment: Unlikely that it's PHP, more likely that it's the browser. It will fall back to HTML entities if it cannot encode the character in the desired encoding. Why *that* is… *mumble mumble handwaive* Latin-1 vs. ANSI vs. actual ISO-8859 something something…?

Comment: Hit Ctrl+U to see the actual text (almost for sure, as deceze points out, HTML entities).

Comment: Yes, it's converted to #+&#180;&#180;+#. Do you know how to "remove" these kind of input?

Comment: HTML-entity-decode it. But preferably, use UTF-8 instead, which can encode practically all characters no matter what.

Comment: No way to get the browser to "remove" these characters?

Comment: I'm afraid it's an intentional strategy used by the browser to deal with characters that do not belong to the document encoding. There's no way to know whether it was typed by user or not. The only reliable fix is switching to UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you so much!